# AngularJS UI-grid Validation

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using UI-Grid for importing CSV in my project. There is no requirement that user can update anything on the uploaded data in the grid.
I need some validations that automatically trigger when I upload the CSV. For example:

- Numeric Check
- One Field should always be less than other field.
- Decimal check
  on the columns.
  In case there is any validation failure, the submit button should be disabled to stop the user to save the data.

Comment: Can you post some code? It's pretty hard to understand what the problem you're experiencing is without code.

Comment: @OceansOnPluto - I am using pretty much the same thing UI Grid documentation suggest. Here is the link for your reference: [UI-Grid](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/207_importing_data)<br/> Let me know if I could explain it further. Thanks!